# How do you evaluate an integral using stokes theorem if the curve given is a unit circle in a plane z=α

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So, C is given as a unit circle in the plane z=α, how would I evaluate this when the formula for stokes asks for the normal vector of a curve but given a slice of a cylinder?

Comment: Please take the time to formulate your problem completely. We are no clairvoyants.

Answer (score 1):

The Stokes Theorem states that
$$\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_S \nabla \times \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_S \nabla \times \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}\; dS, $$
where $S$ is any surface bounded by $C$, with normal unit vector $\vec{n}$.

In your case, $C$ is a unit circle in the plane $z=\alpha$, so a good choice is to consider the surface $S$ as the disc inside $C$, that is :
\begin{align}
&x = r \cos \theta \\
&y = r \sin \theta \quad \quad \mbox{with}\quad 0\le r \le 1, \; 0\le \theta \le 2 \pi\\
&z= \alpha
\end{align}

The normal unit vector $\vec{n}$ is trivially $(0,0,1)$, which should simplify calculations.